# How to make a view in Landscape mode in Portraint mode activity in android?

Tags: android

I have layout which support only portrait mode. In layout there is three tab and onclick of tab, layout will changes. Now, on of the tab has Landscape mode. So when i click on Custom tab, it will move into Landscape mode. I have tried setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); but it will convert the whole layout instead of Linearlayout for Custom tab. I have created the Fragment for the Custom tab. But did not make the fragment in Landscape mode. Can you please help me?

Bottom Tab Menu

```
<!--Bottom Navigation-->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:id="@+id/cnbottm"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_main_chat_background"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_quick_setup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenirnext_regular"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10jdp"
            android:text="Quick Set-up"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteclour"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14jdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quick_custom"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_random"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_random"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenirnext_regular"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10jdp"
            android:text="Random"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14jdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quick_setup"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_random"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8jdp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_random"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quick_setup"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_quicksetup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10jdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10jdp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_quick_setup"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quick_custom"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_random" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_custom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8jdp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_quick_custom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_quick_setup" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_quick_custom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenirnext_regular"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10jdp"
            android:text="Custom"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteclour"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14jdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_quick_setup"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


each tab onclick, it will visible/gone
for other two tabs

     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/liner_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_main_chat_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cnbottm">
    </LinearLayout>

    for custom Tab
    
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/liner_bottom_custom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cnbottm">
    
            <include layout="@layout/actvty_chart_custom_tab"
                />
    
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can try setRotation() on the view you want to rotate?https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29

Comment: i have used rotation with 90 degree but did not get it full screen. i Used match parent for width and height. You can check URL of image. https://imgur.com/a/zc8vivX